# IOS button pressed event?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm would like to know what it is the difference between:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

}
```

and:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender {


}
```

I can see the xcode try to put more extra help with the auto complete when using the id.
so which one is the ***correct*** to use and why?

thanks

Comment: Both are correct, but in first case you can't use `operationPressed` with `switch` or other UIComponents, but in second you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it does not matter: the declared type of `UIButton*` does not guarantee that calls with objects of other types are impossible. The fitst style lets you access properties of `UIButton` with the "dot syntax", while the second style lets you reuse the handler for other UI objects without making your readers wonder what is going on.

For example, if you know that your event handler is used only with buttons, you can declare the type of sender as `UIButton`, and then do this:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
}
```

With the second declaration you would have to write this:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender {
    [sender setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
}
```

On the other hand, if you plan to reuse the handler for different UI objects, the second approach is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a datatype that will hold all other data types, which is useful if you want to store something you dont know the type of at runtime.

In cases where you do know the type (like this one) it's better to use that type over `id` because it uses less bytes to store it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are implementing this method with a specific class (i.e. `UIButton`), Xcode will give you more help. For example, it will autocomplete more stuff and will give you errors if you are sending messages to the button which it can't understand. If the compiler only knew that the sender was of type `id` it wouldn't be able to help you.

On the other hand, if you have several buttons and some of them are a subclass of `UIControl`, but not of `UIButton` and you all want them to trigger `operationPressed`, then you might want to set the sender to type to `UIControl` or `id`.

So basically, in cases where you know what the type of the sender will be, life is easier if you tell Xcode what the type of the sender will be. In cases where you don't know, use `id`.